# Calling search endpoint for Spotify API in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spotify, webapi

I am working on a web api that consumes Spotify API and I can't make the call for the search endpoint. It's my first time making an API consumes other and also my first time using Stack Overflow, so I really don't know how to explain to you, but I will pass part of the code that I think its important.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/spotify/api")
public class SearchController {
    private final AuthSpotifyClient authSpotifyClient;
    private final SearchClient searchClient;

    public SearchController(AuthSpotifyClient authSpotifyClient, SearchClient searchClient) {
        this.authSpotifyClient = authSpotifyClient;
        this.searchClient = searchClient;
    }


    @GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<SearchResponse> search(@RequestBody String q, @RequestBody String type){
        var request = new LoginRequest(
                "confidential",
                "confidential",
                "confidential"
        );
        var token = authSpotifyClient.login(request).getAcessToken();
        var response = searchClient.search("Bearer " + token,
                                            q, type);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}

@FeignClient(
       name = "SearchClient",
        url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?"
)
public interface SearchClient {

    @GetMapping("?q={q}&type={type}")
    SearchResponse search(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization,
                          @PathVariable String q, @PathVariable String type);
}
```

When I run it the endpoint returns 400 Bad Request

Comment: I think you have doubled the question mark in the endpoint url.

Comment: I can see `q` and `type` in the `GetMapping` as request parameters, but in `search` method you mentioned them as `@PathVariable`. Could you please check that again?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is related to the way you're passing query parameters within the Feign client interface. The perfect way to pass query parameters in Feign is to use @RequestParam, not @PathVariable.

```
@FeignClient(
        name = "SearchClient",
        url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1"
)
public interface SearchClient {

    @GetMapping("/search")
    SearchResponse search(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization,
                          @RequestParam("q") String q, @RequestParam("type") String type);
}
```

so your resulting curl will be :

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:your-port/spotify/api/search?q=your-query&type=your-type" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: thanks to feedback! but still there's an error. When I make the request, it returns "HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing" but the body is complete and correct